# У всех ли глаголов можно определить спряжение?

Tags: морфология, спряжение

На одной из олимпиад было такое задание:

«Определите спряжение у глаголов  и объясните, как вы это сделали. С чем  связаны трудности?

*Выглядеть, гнать, гнить, едать ("Не то на серебре — на золоте едал"), засыпáть,  кричать, объять, основать, пилить, храпеть, шить, увидать, выпить, клеить*».

Высшего балла не получил ни один участник. Получается, не такое простое это дело. А как нужно было ответить, по вашему мнению?

Comment: Спасибо за интересный вопрос!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Трудность заключается в том, что **по ИНФИНИТИВУ спряжение всех слов, кроме КЛЕИТЬ, определить невозможно, так как -ать, -еть, -ить в этих глаголах - ударные.** (В глаголе ВЫГЛЯДЕТЬ отбрасываем приставку, которая перетягивает ударение, - ГЛЯДЕТЬ.)

Слово КЛЕИТЬ с безударным -ить в этом ряду - исключение. Спряжение легко определяем и по инфинитиву, и по личным окончаниям.

1 группа глаголов - ударные личные окончания, легко определяем спряжение по ним: ***храпеть (храпишь, храпим, храпят),гнить (гниёшь, гниёт, гниют), кричать (кричит, кричат), шить.***

2 группа глаголов - ограниченные в употреблении, имеющие ограниченное количество форм,  потому определить спряжение по личным окончаниям очень сложно: ***объять , едать, основать, увидать***

3 группа глаголов - с безударными личными окончаниями, по которым можно определить спряжение: ***выглядеть (выглядишь, выглядят), гнать, засыпать, пилить, выпить.***

Comment: Скажите, а почему по ударным -ать, -еть, etc. нельзя определить спряжение?

Comment: Просто общепринятое правило определения спряжения часто не работает, если ударение в инфинитиве падает на последний слог.

Comment: А вы уверены, что это именно ударение виновато? И что вообще несоответствие между ударной тематической гласной и спряжением глагола нарушается достаточно часто, чтобы считать, «что по ИНФИНИТИВУ спряжение всех слов, кроме КЛЕИТЬ, определить невозможно»?

Comment: Екатерина, во 2 группе не сложно определить, а не имеет смысла, ведь тех форм, в которых нужно определять, просто нет.

Comment: В слове клеить (клеит, клеят)  как раз чаще всего и ошибаются, пишут "клеют". Здесь как раз нужно запомнить инфинитив, в нём тоже ошибаются, пишут "клеять".

Comment: Конечно, совершенно с Вами согласна. В слове клеить ошибки допускают очень часто. Но здесь вопрос в другом: как определить спряжение глагола КЛЕИТЬ. Он уже написан. И по инфинитиву, и по личным окончаниям можем определить.

Comment: Aer, несоответствие тематической гласной и спряжения бывает у глаголов с ударными личными окончаниями, а таких, согласитесь, много. Поэтому принято глаголы с ударными -еть, -ать, -ить проверять.

Comment: Екатерина, вот 16 глаголов с ударным тем. гласным: пилить, стрелять, переть, убивать, делить, мутить, родить, пленять, слетать, докучать, пустить, огреть, удушить, перепотрошить, рдеть, теребить. Везде сохранено соответствие между тем. гласным и спряжением (если -и-, то 2-е, если другой — 1-е). Вы могли бы привести столько же или больше разнокоренных глаголов, где это соответствие нарушено, чтобы подтвердить невозможность, о которой вы пишете? Разноспрягаемые глаголы не в счет — это «исключения», есть, дать и проч. — тоже. Мы говорим о нормальных таких, будничных глаголах.

Comment: Лететь, сидеть, глядеть, сопеть, молчать, кричать, стучать, мчать, спать, гореть, дрожать, ушить, сбить, ошибиться, забиться, скорбеть.

Comment: Катерина, разве "объемлет" правильная современная личная форма для "объять"? Даже в словарях не нашел сходу. Только у Даля в гнезде "Объемлить".

Comment: @Aer *Скажите, а почему по ударным -ать, -еть, etc. нельзя определить спряжение?* потому что в случае ударных окончаний инфинитив не является показательным (маркерообразующим). Возникла бы необходимость вводить и запоминать множество исключений, которые ничего бы не давали, поскольку при ударных окончаниях не возникают практические трудности с орфографией. Поэтому сейчас правила формулируются через показатель инфинитива только для  глаголов с  безударными окончаниями. Вот как здесь, например. http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/tipyi-spryajeniya-glagolov-98379.html

Comment: @behemothus, здравствуйте! Хотелось бы сказать, что рада Вам, но здесь это не положено). По поводу личной формы для объять: вопрос Ваш мне нравится, он заставил меня задуматься, и я с удовольствием буду искать ответ, ибо всё это чрезвычайно интересно!)

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова спасибо! В ходе нашего эксперимента мы обнаружили, что все-таки возможно определить спряжение по ударному тем. гласному; тем не менее это работает не всегда, поэтому в методических целях стоит делать это по-другому. Да и вообще надежней сразу смотреть на финитные формы глагола, они дадут точную информацию.

Comment: Совершенно верно! Ударные тем.гласные в инфинитиве в любом случае требуют проверки. А что такое "финитные", я сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: Убрала из ответа слово "объемлет".

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова читай: личные ) прошу прощения — профдеформация )

Answer (score 2):

Точнее всего ответила Екатерина Каштанова, видимо, я принимаю её ответ, но в этом есть какая-то несправедливость: Серж и  Aer тоже близко подошли к решению, им было труднее как первым. Не обижайтесь, ребята, я горжусь, что на этом ресурсе такие грамотные люди, хотя далеко не все филологи. Всем спасибо!

Анализ олимпиады показал, что **ждали от учеников такой ответ:**

Выглядеть — 2 спр.; личные окончания безударные, но глагол имеет приставку вы- , следовательно, спряжение нужно определять по глаголу без этой приставки — глаголу глядеть, имеющему ударные окончания 2 спряжения: глядúшь, глядúт и т.д.

Выпить — 1 спр.; этот глагол также имеет приставку вы-, спряжение определяется по глаголу пить с ударными окончаниями 1 спряжения: пьёшь, пьёт и т.д.

Гнать — 2 спр.; личные окончания безударные, спряжение определяется по инфинитиву, этот глагол включен в список исключений: он на -ать, но 2 спр.

Гнить — 1 спр.; ударные окончания 1 спр.: гниёшь, гниёт и т.д.

Едать — у этого глагола нет личных форм, а также причастий настоящего времени, так что его принадлежность к тому или иному спряжению никак не проявляется.

Засыпáть — 1 спр.; личные окончания глагола безударные, и спряжение определяется по инфинитиву.

Клеить — 2 спр.; этот глагол также имеет безударные окончания, но при определении спряжения по инфинитиву возникает сложность: гласный перед суффиксом  -ть безударен, проверить его нельзя, нужно запоминать, как пишется инфинитив.

Кричать — 2 спр.; ударные окончания 2 спр.: кричúшь, кричúт и т.д.

Объять — личные формы у этого глагола отсутствуют, как и причастия настоящего времени, так что его принадлежность к какому-либо спряжению никак не проявляется.

Основать — 1 спр.; образование личных форм этого глагола затруднено; в «Грамматическом словаре русского языка» А. А. Зализняка отмечено, что формы будущего времени, то есть формы типа оснуёшь, оснуёт и т. д., избегаются; однако такие формы все-таки фиксируются словарями (например, «Орфоэпическим словарем русского языка» под ред. Р. И. Аванесова) и имеют ударные окончания 1 спр.

Пилить — 2 спр.; личные окончания глагола безударные, и спряжение определяется по инфинитиву.

Храпеть — 2 спр.; ударные окончания 2 спр.: храпúшь, храпúт и т.д.

Шить — 1 спр., ударные окончания 1 спр.: шьёшь, шьёт и т.д.

Увидать — личные формы этого глагола отсутствуют, как и причастия настоящего времени, так что его принадлежность к какому-либо спряжению никак не проявляется.

**Обобщение от организаторов олимпиады**.

Сложности, которые могут возникнуть при определении спряжения у глаголов, приведенных в задании, могут быть связаны, во-первых, с уровнем лингвистических знаний выполняющего это действие — с незнанием того, что такое спряжение глагола, и неумением его правильно определять, во-вторых, с особенностями словоизменения ряда глаголов, а именно с отсутствием у них некоторых форм.

Рассмотрим оба источника затруднений подробней. Те, кто у любого глагола определяет спряжение по инфинитиву, совершали ошибки при характеристике глаголов с ударными личными окончаниями, имеющих при этом инфинитив, который указывает на другое спряжение. Это прежде всего глаголы гнить и шить, которые относятся к 1 спряжению, но имеют инфинитив на -ить, а также глаголы кричать и храпеть с инфинитивом на -ать и -еть, относящиеся ко 2 спряжению. Кроме того, нельзя определить по инфинитиву спряжение глаголов выглядеть и выпить, которые сохраняют окончания глаголов глядеть (2 спр.) и пить (1 спр.). У глагола клеить гласный в инфинитиве сам безударен, поэтому, чтобы определить спряжение правильно, необходимо записать эту форму без ошибок. Во всех этих случаях главное — знать, в каких случаях классическое орфографическое правило, регулирующее написание личных окончаний глагола, применимо, а в каких — нет.

Comment: _Людмила: Точнее всего ответила Екатерина Каштанова..._ === Вы и с этим согласны в её ответе: _"по ИНФИНИТИВУ спряжение всех слов, кроме КЛЕИТЬ, определить невозможно, **так как -ать, -еть, -ить в этих глаголах - ударные**"_?

Comment: Я хотела сказать, что все глаголы, кроме клеить, нужно проверять дополнительно, не ориентируясь только на гласную перед -ТЬ.

Comment: Эх, Людмила... рано вы ответы дали...  Я-то, оказывается, угадал подход. Мог бы на законных основаниях поучаствовать в нашей внутренней  олимпиаде... Но видит Бог, отвечал честно, не подсматривая.

Comment: Людмила, из всего сказанного у меня вызвало вопрос только отнесение глагола "основать" к недостаточным - по формам настоящего времени. К таковым относят обычно только глаголы с совершенно неупотребительными отдельными формами или вовсе не имеющие таковых. у "Основать" эти формы максимум не совсем свободны, но до некоторой степени употребительны. Поэтому я даже не стал думать о каких-то сложностях по этой части. Или чего-то не так понял?

Comment: _Екатерина Каштанова: Я хотела сказать, что все глаголы, кроме клеить, **нужно проверять дополнительно**, не ориентируясь только на гласную перед -ТЬ._ ===  По-моему, у Вас с ног на голову перевёрнутый подход к методике определения спряжения у глаголов. То, что вы считаете "дополнительным", на самом деле должно стоять на первом месте при определении спряжения...

Comment: @behemothus, про "основать" ведь и сказано не то, что нельзя определить спряжение, а что трудно, потому что  его формы почти неупотребительны, ну вот я, например, про оснуёт и не подумала бы, это что-то устаревшее, просторечное, но раз где-то употребляется - значит, есть.

Comment: @Людмила для меня осну'и, осную - вполне себе употребительные формы.. Но я не об этом. Вы характеризуете глагол "основать"  как глагол, для которого наблюдаются сложности с определением типа спряжения. Ну допустим, сами формы неупотребительны, но разве это доставляет какие-то сложности в плане определения типа склонения? Я могу отчасти (именно отчасти, подробности опускаю)  признать такие сложности если нужные формы вообще отсутствуют и не подлежат реконструкции, но тут-то все на ладони.

Comment: Можно спорить, насколько форма жизненна, но её вид, то какая именно форма подразумевается, сомнений не вызывает. Так в чем сложность-то? То  есть по моим понятиям, отнесение к рассматриваемому списку (глаголов, вызывающих затруднение в определении их типа спряжения) слова "основать" ничем не оправдано. Вот я о чем.

Comment: Так ведь вопрос-то для детей, вряд ли они такие формы знают. Дети определили по конечному -ать -1 спр., так и объяснили, а это неверно, потому и не засчитали ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, предполагалось, что участники заметят «проблемность» парадигмы:

Выглядеть, гнать — ко второму, исключения. Гнить, едать, засыпать, объять, основать, шить, увидать, выпить — к первому. Остальные ко второму. Как сделали? Получили формы, которые указывают на принадлежность к тому или иному спряжению (гоним, выглядим; шьющий, оснуют, увидаем и т. д.). Трудности связаны... ну, в некоторых местах (основать) формы глагола архаичны, хотя, в приниципе, ничто не мешает посмотреть на инфинитив. Некоторые глаголы «недостаточные»: объять не имеет форм причастия наст. вр., например. Но только это не такая уж и трудность.

Comment: А почему выглядеть - исключение? Это же не смотреть. Здесь другой принцип: если есть приставка вы-, нужно её убрать - окончание будет ударным: глядеть, глядит, глядят - 2 спр. Выпить - пить, пьёт, пьют - 1 спр.

Comment: Основать —  согласна, 1 спр.; но образование личных форм этого глагола затруднено; в «Грамматическом словаре русского языка» А. А. Зализняка отмечено, что формы буд. времени, то есть формы типа оснуёшь, оснуёт и т. д., избегаются; однако такие формы все-таки фиксируются словарями (например, «Орфоэпическим словарем русского языка» под ред. Р. И. Аванесова) и имеют ударные окончания 1 спр. А увидаем Вы где взяли? Это наст., буд. время?

Comment: @Людмила выгляд**е**ть в инфинитиве, а набор окончаний второго спряжения. В школьной грамматике такое соответствие закреплено за исключениями. А что там отбросить — другое дело, это методическое указание.

Comment: Увидаем — из головы, но, видимо, есть еще какая-то песенка про Масленицу, где эта форма употреблена (видимо, как просторечная). Будущего конечно; как же у глаголов такого типа найти форму настоящего времени?

Comment: Aer, в школьной грамматике  во 2 спр. 11 исключений : гнать, держать, смотреть и видеть, дышать, слышать, ненавидеть, и зависеть, и терпеть, и обидеть, и вертеть +   4 исключения 1 спр.: брить, стелить, зиждиться, зыбиться.

Comment: @Людмила а что же тогда «выглядеть», «углядеть», «приглядеть»? «Есть», «дать»?  Сколько бы там ни было исключений (вы, кстати, привели слишком уж много слов первого спряжения; в рядовой школе обходятся двумя против ваших четырех), суть происходящего не меняется.

Comment: @Людмила  _Не можно дальше дикарями в лесу жить. Пусть хоть дети свет **увидают…_** (В. Астафьев. Царь-рыба). Раньше в школе это произведение было всем известно.

Comment: Ну, это диалект, не считается. Мы же о нормированном языке говорим.

Comment: @Людмила а вы считаете удовлетворительным то, что у глагола «в диалекте», равно как и в головах людей, есть спряжение, а в нормированном языке — нет?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, трудности связаны с глаголами едать и объять. Вообще задание странное.

В словарях говорится, что у глагола "едать" наст. вр. нет ( Ушаков, Лопатин).

Однако в словаре Зализняка глагол "едать" относится к первому спряжению. И напротив, в том же словаре Зализняка(Грамматический словарь русского языка: Словоизменение. Зализняк А.А. - М.: "АСТ-ПРЕСС", 2008. - 794 с.)говорится, что слово "объять" не соотносится ни с одним спряжением.

В Большом толковом словаре под редакцией Кузнецова у глагола "объять" представлено будущее время - обойму, обоймёшь. В словаре Ожегова говорится, что буд. вр. нет у этого глагола.

На другом сайте встретил полное спряжение этого глагола.

Наверное, на уровне школьной грамматики ответ в этих двух глаголах.

Comment: У глагола едать  нет личных форм, а также причастий настоящего времени, так что его принадлежность к тому или иному спряжению никак не проявляется. Спряжение — это, с одной стороны, изменение глаголов по лицам и числам, а с другой — это одинаковые наборы личных окончаний. Нет личных окончаний - нет спряжения.

Comment: У глагола объять отсутствие личных и причастных форм маскируется внешне похожими на него формами других глаголов: объемлет, объемлющий, обнимет. Глагол объять относится к сов. виду и поэтому не может иметь никаких форм наст. времени, в том числе и форм объемлет, объемлющий. Эти формы принадлежат не ему, а соответствующему глаголу несов. вида, не имеющему инфинитива. Форма обнимет  принадлежит  глаголу обнять.

Comment: По-Ушакову: обыму, обымешь и обойму, обоймёшь, сов. к обнимать, что (инф. и прош. - книжн. ритор. устар., буд. - простореч.; ср. отнять). Так что  у глагола объять тоже нельзя определить спряжение. Но есть ещё один подобный глагол.

Comment: @Людмила, т. е. обыму, обымешь и обойму, обоймёшь тоже принадлежат соответствующему глаголу несов. вида, не имеющему инфинитива? что это за глагол?

Comment: У Зализняка: еда́ть,
еда́ю,
еда́ем,
еда́ешь,
еда́ете,
еда́ет,
еда́ют,
еда́я

Comment: Нет, это я так непонятно скопировала. Обыму, обымешь - просторечия будущего времени. В нормированном языке таких форм нет. Обоймёшь, обойму - формы сов.вида к глаголу обнимать. Инфинитив объять и прош.вр. объял - это устаревшее и торж. - риторическое, т.е. поэтическое. Может, потому что это старославянизм, поэтому и парадигма не развивается, застыла, развиваются парадигмы русских слов.

Comment: Серж, у Зализняка в его словаре собраны все возможные формы - и устаревшие, и просторечные, и даже диалектные, но ведь вопросы на олимпиадах касаются только процессов русского языка, а не речи. Надеюсь, Вы не скажете: "Я каждый день едаю...". А вот "Бывало, я едал ..." - легко.

Comment: Ну, да, если учитывать современный язык, вы правы. Я даже ''едал" не скажу. Не смогу.

Comment: @Людмила,ну так вопрос решился? В олимпиаде имелись в виду эти глаголы? Или есть какой-то еще подвох?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы ответила так.

Можно выделить пять групп глаголов.

**Группа 1.** Спряжение определяется для глаголов с безударными личными окончаниями **по стандартным правилам:** гнать, засыпать, пилить, клеить.

**Группа 2.** Спряжение определяется по ударному личному окончанию, причем глаголы с приставкой ВЫ имеют то же спряжение, что и без приставки: выглядеть,  гнить,   кричать,  храпеть, шить, выпить.

**Группа 3.** Видовая пара  объять/обнимать. Объять (сов. вид) – обоймет, обоймешь. Обнимать (несов.вид) – обнимает и объемлет (устар.).

Обоймёт (что сделает) – будущее время.

**Группа 4. Устаревшие формы имеют глаголы**: основать (оснуёт), увидать (увидает).

**Группа 5**. Глагол ***едать*** не имеет личных форм.

Примеры:

Номер восемнадцать **увидаю** ― так сердце и замрет. [Б. В. Шергин. У Архангельского города (1930-1960)]

Пока этот смысл только мельком указывается, но затем на нем именно Инквизитор и **оснует** свое отрицание. [В. В. Розанов. Легенда о Великом инквизиторе Ф. М. Достоевского (1893-1906)]

Либо вокруг глядим… а вокруг все поля идут ― глазом не **обоймешь,** а там села, деревни, хутора… [А. И. Эртель. Записки Степняка (1883)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

В дополнение к уже данному ответу я попробую представить еще **общий план решения.**

1. Выделяем глаголы с безударными личными окончаниями, которые решаются **по стандартному правилу,** то есть по гласной перед ТЬ (с учетом  глаголов-исключений). Эти правила знает каждый школьник, а не только "олимпийцы".
2. Вспоминаем **дополнительное правило,** о котором простые школьники могут забыть. Основное правило определения спряжения **применяется только для глаголов с безударными окончаниями.**

Если глагол имеет ударные личные окончания, то помощь в определении спряжения ему не требуется (мы и так видим, какое у него спряжение).

3. Ряд глаголов требуют **индивидуального подхода,** в том числе глаголы из представленного списка.

а) Это глаголы **с приставкой ВЫ,** для которых и контроль безударного глагольного суффикса, и выбор личного окончания делается без учета этой приставки (перетягивающей на себя ударение).

б) Некоторые глаголы могут **не иметь личных форм** (едать) или их **личные формы относятся к устаревающим** и малоупотребительным (основать, увидать, объять).

Answer (score 1):

Я отвечу, предварительно не читая, хотя знаю, что наверняка пойду вразрез с общим мнением. Потом почитаю ответы.

Во-первых, не люблю подобные формулировки, когда остается гадать, что хотел услышать спрашивающий.
Во-вторых, строго говоря, "спряжение" есть некая система личных (или лично-временных) форм, существующая (или сопоставляемая) **каждому** глаголу. Следовательно, спряжение есть у **каждого** глагола. И что собственно, мешает определить его тип? Смотришь в словарь - видишь, по какому образцу глагол спрягается.

Ну допустим, предполагается, что определить тип спряжения надо самостоятельно, без словаря. Но тогда вся трудность заключается в том, знает ли участник олимпиады правильные формы спряжений упомянутых глаголов. Эко дело...

Итак, мой ответ.
Тип спряжения можно определить у любого глагола, если знать все его правильные личные формы. Если не знать, то наверняка сказать невозможно, хотя обычно достаточно одной-двух. Единственная сложность заключается в существовании разноспрягаемых и неправильных глаголов и глаголов, имеющих вариативные формы (типа стлать-стелить, мерить-мерять).
Но это очень условная "трудность", ибо такие глаголы тоже можно и нужно как-то классифицировать, то есть отнести к определенному типу склонения - разноспрягаемых, неправильных или "парноспрягаемых" (назовем так).

Судя по всему, авторы вопроса просто хотели в очередной раз проверить, знают ли участники, как спрягается каждый глагол из списка...

Откровенно говоря, без интернета я не берусь утверждать, что вспомню все тонкости... Да и с интернетом наверняка можно что-то пропустить или попасть в пропасть между академическими и школьными представлениями..

В приведенном списке вижу (без шпаргалки) следующее:

**Выглядеть** - спрягается как и "гдядеть", то есть по второму спряжению. "Сложность" в переносе ударения на приставку, но абсолютное большинство приставочных глаголов сохраняют тип спряжения (я бы сказал **все**, но смутно помню, что есть какое-то исключение)

**гнать** - так называемый глагол-исключение, относится ко второму спряжению, хотя инфинитив имеет признаки первого. В этом, видимо и "сложность"

**гнить** глагол первого спряжения, окончание личных форм ударное, инфинитив не является маркером спряжения. Что тут сложного, даже не знаю, возможно только фонетическая и смысловая близость с родственным глаголом "гноить", который является глаголом второго спряжения

**едать** - глагол первого спряжения (он едает, они едают), сложность, видимо, в том, что формы настоящего времени совершенно неупотребительны и восстанавливаются только косвенным путем. Но это и есть тип спряжения глагола, этот тип можно назвать "недостаточным".

**засыпáть** -это глагол вариативный, имеющий для отдельных личных форм два варианта. Засыпет - засыплет, засыпают - засыплют. Тем не менее это глагол первого спряжения для обеих форм. Сложностей не вижу. Возможно, к таковым авторы относят омографическое сходство с глаголом засыпАть, но тогда это уже надумано.

**кричать** -  вот не понял вообще, что сложного тут. Второе спряжение, кричишь - кричат, ударные окончания (или их теперь правильно суффиксами называть?)

**объять** - глагол "неправильный" в части чередования в основе. Обоймёт-обоймут, окончание ударное, перваое спряжение без вопросов. Сложность разве что в исторически "парной" форме "обнять", с той же основой, но с другой ступенью корневого чередования.

**основать** - первое спряжение. Предположений о каких-то сложностях нет.

**пилить** - безударное окончания с ненормативной вариативностью формы ед-3 мн-3 [пилит-пилят и (неправильное)пилет-пилют], глагол второго спряжения.

**храпеть** - глагол второго спряжения личное окончание ударное, форма инфинитива не показательна.

**шить** - первое спряжение, ударное личное окончание, форма инфинитива не показательна.

**увидать** - аналогично "едал", глагол первого спряжения с недостаточностью форма настоящего времени. Дополнительная сложность - созвучие с глаголом "увядал".

**выпить** - второе спряжение, как и со словом "выглядеть", вся сложность только в ударной приставке.

**клеить** - ха... а вот действительно не совсем простое слово... Глагол второго спряжения, все абсолютно по основному правилу - то есть по форме инфинитива на "-ить".
Но в русском языке не так много глаголов (если вообще есть общеупотребительные), с основой на "-**е**й", да еще сохраняющих ударение на основе в личных формах. Поэтому нормативные формы кл**еи**т и кл**ея**т несвободны и часто ошибочно воспринимаются носителями как кл**ее**т и кл**е**т - по ложной аналогии с представителями более распространенной модели: греть-гр**ее**т-гр**ею**т, зеленеть-зелен**ее**т-зелен**ею**т и проч.

*Уффф... Пошел читать правильные ответы... Опечатки позже поправлю*

(+)=====

Моё засЫпать - это я сослепу не там ударение поставил. Но с "засыпАть" тем более нет сложностей.

Answer (score 1):

Короче, даю еще один ответ - на другой аспект вопроса.

Я понял, что искомые "сложности" возникают у тех авторов и учащихся, кто не до конца понимает школьное правило определения типа спряжения.

Вот вариант, который полностью исключает попытки применить классификацию по форме инфинитива для глаголов с ударным окончанием (или "личным суффиксом", как иногда называют).

> ***Если окончание ударное, спряжение определяет­ся по окончанию (см.
>   таблицу): печёшь — I спр., сидишь — II спр.***
>
> ***Примечание. Глаголы с ударным личным окончанием нельзя ставить в
>   инфинитив для определения спряжения.***
>
> Если окончание безударное, спряжение глагола определяется по
>   инфинитиву.
>
> Ко второму спряжению относятся те глаголы с безударным личным
>   окончанием, которые в инфинитиве оканчиваются:
>
> 1) на -итъ: лакомиться, ездить, готовить и т. д. Исключения — брить,
>   стелить, зыбиться» зиж­диться (I спр.);
>
> 2) на -ать (4 глагола): гнать» держать» слышать, дышать» а также
>   образованные от них при помощи приставки и постфикса: выгнать,
>   удержать» дер­жаться в т. п.;
>
> 3) на -еть (7 глаголов): терпеть, вертеть, оби­деть» зависеть,
>   ненавидеть, видеть, смотреть; а также образованные от них
>   приставочным, постфиксальным либо приставочно-постфиксальным способом:
>   высмотреть, обидеться, смотреться и др,
>
> Все остальные глаголы с безударным лич­ным окончанием относятся к
>   первому спряжению: гулять, умываться, жалеть, колоть и т. д.
>
> Глаголы хотеть, бежать и образованные от них (перехотеть, захотеть,
>   забежать, выбежать и т. д.) являются разноспрягаемыми, так как имеют
>   окончания разных спряжений. Окончания разных спряжений имеет и глагол
>   брезжить, употребляю­щийся в формах только 3-го лица.

http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/tipyi-spryajeniya-glagolov-98379.html
*(курсив мой - b-s)*

Всё. Забудьте об инфинитиве для глаголов с ударным личным окончанием - и никаких сложностей тут не будет.