# Имеет ли глагол "объять" личные окончания?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы

**Вот что говорят  филологи:**

"Объять — **личные формы у этого глагола отсутствуют**, как и причастия настоящего времени, так что его принадлежность к какому-либо спряжению никак не проявляется".

[У всех ли глаголов можно определить спряжение?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447391/%D0%A3-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Но обратимся к словарю:

**ОБЪЯТЬ**, обойму, **обоймёшь**; объял, св. кого-что. **Книжн**. =Обнять.

**Из Нацкорпуса:**

Однако бывало: милое оканье обласкает вдруг слух твой, встретишься с душой нараспашку, послушаешь разговор о житейских заботишках, и сладкая наволочь **обоймет** сердце...  [Алексей Иванов. За рекой, за речкой (1982)]

Это проза, которая **обоймет** все, что я знаю «лучше всех на свете» со времен Прасолова до наших дней... ,[А. Т. Твардовский. Из рабочих тетрадей (1957) // «Знамя», 1989]

И собой хороша младшая доченька… Ну, может, не такая красавица, какими удались старшие ― сами вбеле румяны, косу русую пальцами **не обоймёшь,** ― но тоже не из таких, от кого люди с жалостью отводят глаза...  ” [Мария Семенова. Волкодав: Знамение пути (2003)]

Безусловно, **личная форма глагола устаревает**, раньше она применялась намного чаще. Но для высокого стиля, для стилизации под старину вполне подходит, просто **стилистическую** пометку надо бы изменить.

**Но можно ли утверждать, что эта личная форма не существует?** Я бы сочла такое утверждение за ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня есть "Новый орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Произношение. Ударение. Грамматические нормы". Автор Иванова Т.Ф., М., ДРОФА, 2008

Привожу статью из словаря:

**ОБЪЯТЬ**, *буд.неуп*;

*прош*. объял, объяла, объяло, объяли;

*пов. неуп.*;

*прич.действ.прош.* объявший, -ая, -ее, -ие; *дееприч*. объяв

**ОБЪЯТЫЙ** (*прич.страд.прош*.к объять); кр.ф. объят, объято, объята, объяты.

Обойми меня, друг мой сердечный! Вот сынок, одно мое утешение. ... (Д.И.Фонвизин. "Недоросль") Эта форма "обойми" - устаревшая форма повелительного наклонения глагола "объять". В словаре Ивановой уже видим:*пов.неуп.*

Но думаю, что утверждение об отсутствии личных форм у этого слова ошибочно. Они по крайней мере существуют и навсегда останутся в русской классической литературе.

Comment: Да, я согласна с Вами: существуют и навсегда останутся в русской классической литературе. "Туман разойдется, и ночь обоймет..." (Б. Пастернак). И это нам предлагают считать  просторечными формами?

Comment: Нет, Екатерина, обойми - это не форма глагола объять - это просторечная  форма глагола обнять. Не обратили внимание, что это речь неграмотной барыни, которая и сыну учиться не советует? Так что Иванова права, да и другие словари говорят о том же.

Comment: ОБЪЯ́ТЬ, обыму, обымешь и обойму, обоймёшь, совер. (к обнимать), что (инф. и прош. вр. - книжн. ритор. устар., буд. вр. - прост.; срн. отнять). То же, что обнять во 2, 3 и 4 знач. «Сидел Ермак, объятый думой.» Рылеев. «Тогда, отчаяньем объят, я разревелся пред судом.» Некрасов. «Никто не может объять необъятное.» Козьма Прутков.

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

Comment: Обойми - это действительно просторечная форма. Но это форма глагола "объять", а не обнять. Обойму - обойми.

Answer (score 3):

Из [**Грамматики—80:**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1562-1575.html)

> **§ 1569**
>
> <…>
>
> Глаголы *объять, отъять, подъять и разъять* (все – книжн.) имеют
>   только формы прош. вр. и формы, образующиеся от основы прош. вр.:
>   *объя-л-а, объя-вш-ий, объя-т-ый, объя-в(ши)*. Личные формы и формы, образующиеся от основы наст. вр., стилистически не соотносятся с
>   формой инфинитива и формами, образуемыми от основы наст. вр. Формы
>   *обымут* и *обоймут*, *обыми* и *обойми*, *подымут*, *подыми*, *разымут*, *разыми* входят в неполные парадигмы глаголов, состоящие из личных форм и форм повелит. накл.
>
> Формы эти – просторечные и употребляются в целях стилизации.

Comment: А с какого времени они стали считаться просторечными, раньше использовались как обычные.  В современной поэзии  тоже встречаются не так уж редко и не как стилизованные. Можно назвать их устаревающими или устаревшими, но почему просторечными. Вроде бы это не одно и то же.  http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EE%E1%EE%E9%EC%E5%F2

Comment: А такое высказывание: "Обоймёшь, обойму -  это формы сов.вида к глаголу обнимать", оно верно?  Откуда всё это берется, на каких основаниях? Форма глагола "объять" передается глаголу "обнять".

Comment: _Sharon: А такое высказывание: "Обоймёшь, обойму - это формы сов.вида к глаголу обнимать", оно верно?  Откуда всё это берется, на каких основаниях? Форма глагола "объять" передается глаголу "обнять"._ === Есть (во всяком случае, была раньше) такая детская игра — "испорченный телефон". В словаре было одно, Людмила часть словарной статьи подсократила... Если обратитесь к первоисточнику (в данном случае — к словарю Ушакова) часть вопросов у Вас отпадёт.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, я обращусь. Просто детективная какая-то история с этим словом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот полная акцентуированная парадигма в словаре А. А. Зализняка - объят

объя'ть, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, объя'л, объя'ла, объя'ло, объя'ли, -, -, объя'вший, объя'вшая, объя'вшее, объя'вшие, объя'вшего, объя'вшей, объя'вшего, объя'вших, объя'вшему, объя'вшей, объя'вшему, объя'вшим, объя'вший, объя'вшую, объя'вшее, объя'вшие, объя'вшего, объя'вшую, объя'вшее, объя'вших, объя'вшим, объя'вшей, объя'вшею, объя'вшим, объя'вшими, объя'вшем, объя'вшей, объя'вшем, объя'вших, объя'тый, объя'тая, объя'тое, объя'тые, объя'того, объя'той, объя'того, объя'тых, объя'тому, объя'той, объя'тому, объя'тым, объя'тый, объя'тую, объя'тое, объя'тые, объя'того, объя'тую, объя'тое, объя'тых, объя'тым, объя'той, объя'тою, объя'тым, объя'тыми, объя'том, объя'той, объя'том, объя'тых, объя'т, объя'та, объя'то, объя'ты

http://www.xn--80aacc4bir7b.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C

**Обнять** у него даётся отдельно: обниму', обни'мем, обни'мешь, обни'мете, обни'мет, обни'мут. Как видите, накакого  **обойму** здесь нет, это просторечие, в поэзии используется для стилизации народной речи.

В пособии для студентов:

**Не изменяется по лицам и не имеет формы будущего времени глагол объять;** 
https://vuzlit.ru/843962/mesto_glagola_sisteme_chastey_rechi_russkogo_yazyka_vopros_obeme_glagolnoy_paradigmy

По-моему, понятно, что если не изменяется по лицам, то таких форм **нет**.

Слова, конечно, родственные с исторической точки зрения. Мало того, основы слов объять, обнять, объемлет восходят к одному корню  в ПИЕ: *em-, *m̥- со значением «брать». В праславянском они обозначали, по-видимому, различные времена одного глагола, а дальше их значения стали расходиться.

Морфологическое гнездо основ **jяти — имати — имети — jемлити  (имети — jемлити) и  (jяти — имати**). В совр. словах:

jяти: обнять, взять, принять, отнять, внять, изъять и т. д.

имати: обнимать, взимать, принимать, отнимать, внимать, изымать и т. д.

jемлити: объемлеть, приемлеть, отъемлеть, внемлить и т. д.

имети: иметь, возыметь и т. д.

Слово **обнять**  произошло от старослав. слова **объять** (охватить, обнять, окружить), праслав. *OBЪ-JĘTI. Собственно русская форма - ОБНЯТЬ, со вставным Н, проникшим из СЪН-ЯТИ, ВЪН-ЯТИ в результате переразложения в СЪ-НЯТИ, ВЪ-НЯТИ.

Глагол ОБНЯТЬ ещё в 19-м веке (как видим из классики) употреблялся не только в значении "обнять", но и "объять, охватить". Так часто бывает, слова разного происхождения часто употребляются как синонимы, а потом что-то устаревает, исчезает, остаётся одно слово.

Но сейчас у них разные значения: под обнять мы подразумеваем кого-то или что-то конкретное, а с "объять" употребляем абстрактные понятия - охватить со всех сторон, включить в свой состав, постигнуть(книжн.).

Comment: Ну вот я читаю: "Распахнет она Тучу черную, Обоймет  (= охватит со всех сторон) тебя Ветром -холодом..." Так что, этой формы не существует? Она стала просторечной? Ну, в значении "обнять" слово устарело, но значение "охватить со всех сторон" осталось.  Так назовите ее устаревшей, хотя она используется в современной поэзии, но только не делайте вид, что ее вовсе  нет. И не хотелось бы, чтобы высокую поэзию переводили в просторечие, хотя я надеюсь, что язык  не так податлив, как кажется нашим ученым и грамотным людям.

Comment: _Людмила: Вот полная акцентуированная парадигма в словаре А. А. Зализняка..._ === Не совсем полная. В приведённой Вами парадигме нет имеющейся у Зализняка формы деепр. прош. _объяв(ши)_.

Comment: Ну, это уже не от меня, я скопировала всё, что было в этом словаре, другое дело, что их никто не проверяет, ошибки стали часты, поэтому в научных работах используют только словари на бумажных носителях. Меня причастия-деепричастия не интересовали, главное, что личных форм глагола нет.